# SimpleXML : using id attribute for multiple types

Tags: java, xml, simple-framework

I am using SimpleXML for parsing XML to Java objects, but I am not able to parse this file :

```xml
<pets>
    <cats>
        <cat id="0" talk="miaou" />
        <cat id="1" talk="MIWAOUHAUOHou" />
    </cats>
    <dogs>
        <dog id="0"/>
    </dogs>
    <mine>
        <cat ref="1"/>
    </mine>
</pets>
```

Using this Java class :

```java
@Default
@Root(name = "pets")
public class SimpleIds
{
    @ElementList(required = false)
    public ArrayList<Cat> cats;

    @ElementList(required = false)
    public ArrayList<Dog> dogs;

    @Root(name = "cat")
    public static class Cat
    {
        @Attribute
        public String talk;

        public void talk()
        {
            System.out.println(talk);
        }
    }

    @Root(name = "dog")
    public static class Dog
    {

    }

    @Element
    public Mine mine;

    @Root(name = "mine")
    public static class Mine
    {
        @Element
        public Cat cat;
    }
}
```

And this Serializer :

```
Strategy strategy = new CycleStrategy("id", "ref");
Serializer serializer = new Persister(strategy);
SimpleIds xml = serializer.read(SimpleIds.class, new File("simpleIds.xml"));
xml.mine.cat.talk();
```

It throws me not kindly :

```
org.simpleframework.xml.strategy.CycleException: Element '0' already exists
```

Is it impossible to use this kind of xml files with SimpleXML ? Or is it just a bad xml format ?

**Edit** : If I change `cat id="0"` to `cat id="2"` it works like a charm...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finaly I found an answer in [W3C Recommendation](http://www.w3.org/TR/xml-id/#processing) :

> The values of **all attributes** of type “ID” (which includes all xml:id attributes) within a document are **unique**.

Which means my input XML is **not correct**.

I cannot change it because I receive it from a software but I will have to format it before reading it (and reverse to write it back) to get something like this :

```xml
<pets>
    <cats>
        <cat id="cat-0" talk="miaou" />
        <cat id="cat-1" talk="MIWAOUHAUOHou" />
    </cats>
    <dogs>
        <dog id="dog-0"/>
    </dogs>
    <mine>
        <cat ref="cat-1"/>
    </mine>
</pets>
```

**Edit** : Here is the code that can do the stuff automaticaly for you in SimpleXML :

```java
/*
 * Copyright (C) 2014, Mathieu Lavigne <bludwarf@gmail.com>
 *
 * Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
 * you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
 * You may obtain a copy of the License at
 *
 *     http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 * distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
 * WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or 
 * implied. See the License for the specific language governing 
 * permissions and limitations under the License.
 */
package org.simpleframework.xml.strategy;

import static org.simpleframework.xml.strategy.Name.*;

import java.util.Map;

import org.simpleframework.xml.core.Persister;
import org.simpleframework.xml.stream.Node;
import org.simpleframework.xml.stream.NodeMap;

/**
 * CycleStrategy for SimpleXML allowing having duplicate IDs on nodes from different types.
 * 
 * <p>Known limitations : </p>
 * 
 * <ul>
 * <li>as for Legacy CycleStrategy, new ids are generated for <b>every node</b> when calling {@link Persister#write(Object, java.io.File)}
 * </ul>
 * 
 * @author bludwarf@gmail.com
 * @since 26 juin 2014
 */
public class TypedCycleStrategy extends CycleStrategy
{
    private String mark;
    private String refer;

    public TypedCycleStrategy()
    {
        this(MARK, REFER, LABEL, LENGTH);
    }

    public TypedCycleStrategy(String mark, String refer)
    {
        this(mark, refer, LABEL, LENGTH);
    }

    public TypedCycleStrategy(String mark, String refer, String label)
    {
        this(mark, refer, label, LENGTH);
    }


    public TypedCycleStrategy(String mark, String refer, String label, String length)
    {
        super(mark, refer, label, length);
        this.mark = mark;
        this.refer = refer;
    }

    public Value read(Type type, NodeMap node, Map map)
            throws Exception
    {
        // Unique id
        makeUniqueAttribute(mark, node, type);

        // Unique ref
        makeUniqueAttribute(refer, node, type);

        return super.read(type, node, map);
    }


    /**
     * @param attribute mark OR refer
     * @param node current node
     * @param type node type
     * @return the uniqueId created
     * @throws Exception
     */
    public static String makeUniqueAttribute(String attribute, NodeMap node, Type type) throws Exception
    {
        final Node entry = node.remove(attribute);
        String uniqueId = null;

        // Attribute found ?
        if (entry != null)
        {
            // Replace it to make it unique
            final String id = entry.getValue();
            uniqueId = type.getType().getName() + "-" + id;
            node.put(attribute, uniqueId);
        }

        return uniqueId;
    }

}
```

Notes : **do not change the package declaration !**

And the corresponding Serializer :

```java
Strategy strategy = new TypedCycleStrategy("id", "ref");
Serializer serializer = new Persister(strategy);
SimpleIds xml = serializer.read(SimpleIds.class, new File("simpleIds.xml"));
xml.mine.cat.talk();
```

Answer (score 1):

In the constructor for CycleStrategy you can pass in parameters to specify whether to use "id" as the attribute to identitfy elements or something else. Here the exception is caused because it noticed two elements with the same "id". Try this

```
CycleStrategy s = new CyctleStragegy("myid", "myreference")
```

It will work.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @ng. I was already using CycleStrategy with parameters. I edited my question.

Answer (score 0):

Your XML is perfect. I don't know about Simple Framework But i have done with JAXB.

I have Used JAXB if it Helps.

Here is The Perfect Example.

```
@XmlRootElement(name ="cat")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Cat {

    private String catName;
    private int id;

        Getters And Setters
}

@XmlRootElement(name ="dog")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Dog {

    private String dogName;
        private int id;
        Getters And Setters
}

@XmlRootElement(name = "cats")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Cats {

    @XmlElement(name = "cat")
    private List<Cat> cats;
        Getters And Setters
}


@XmlRootElement(name = "dogs")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Dogs {

    @XmlElement(name = "dog")
    private List<Dog> dogs;
        Getters And Setters
}

@XmlRootElement(name ="pets")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Pet {

    @XmlElement
    private Dogs dogs; 
    @XmlElement
    private Cats cats;
        Getters And Setters
}
```

I have tested it please test it.

Comment: Thank you @Kshitij for the time you spent. I would like to use SimpleXML, as my main goal in to process much more complex XML files. I will use your solution, if it cannot be achieve with SimpleXML.